# Angular with in memory data service: api/"something" not found

Tags: angular, angular-in-memory-web-api

I am trying to use InMemoryDbService as data source in Angular 14.0.2 (/Node 16.15.1) project.
I'm getting "api/[something]" not found in the browser log, no other apparent error.
I can't share the whole code but I'll try to replicate the relevant parts here.

**app.module.ts**

```ts
    (...)
import { HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryDataService } from './in-memory-data.service';

    (...)
  imports: [
    (...)
      HttpClientModule,
      HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService, {dataEncapsulation:false}),
    ThingsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
    (...)
```

**in-memory-data.service.ts**

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { MockThings } from './thing/mock-thing-list';
import { Thing} from './thing/thing';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {

    createDb() {
        const Things: Thing[] = MockThings;
        return { Things};
    }

}
```

**thing.service.ts**

```ts
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { catchError, Observable, of, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { Things} from './thing';

@Injectable()
export class ThingService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getThingsList(): Observable<Thing[]> {
        return this.http.get<Thing[]>('api/things').pipe(
            tap((response) => this.log(response)),
            catchError((error) => this.handleError(error, []))
        );
    }

private log(response: Thing[] | Thing| undefined) {
    console.table(response);
}

private handleError(error: Error, errorValue: any) {
    console.error(error);
    return of(errorValue);
}


(...)
}
```

**thing-list.component.ts**

```ts
(...)

@Component({
  selector: 'app-thing-list',
  templateUrl: './thing-list.component.html',
})

export class ThingListComponent implements OnInit {
    Things: Thing[];
    selectedThing: Thing|undefined;

    constructor(private router: Router, private thingService: ThingService ) {

    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.ThingService .getThingList().subscribe(thingList => this.Things);
    }

    (...)
}
```

Comment: angular 16 is not a thing

Comment: @R.Richards Sorry about that, what it Angular v16.15.1 supposed to be then?

Comment: Do you mean [node v16.15.1](https://nodejs.org/ro/blog/release/v16.15.1/) ?

Comment: Look in your package.json file to see what version of angular you are working with

Comment: Ok sorry, I confused Angular and Node version (I'm in my first days with both).

Comment: can you include the exact error log?

Comment: The fact that a simple typo fix solved your problem means this question should remain closed. The close reason is wrong, out reopening would just lead to another round of votes to close as typo / unreproducible. Simple misspellings are unlikely to help future visitors, and thus are not worth keeping.

Comment: It was not a typo, it was a choice, and I just learned two things: route URLs are generated based on that variable name (case included) + routes URL are case sensitive ... In general, standard URLs are not case sensitive, I would not have expected this path to be case sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't it be in camelCase? `Things` -> `things`

```
 const things: Thing[] = MockThings;
 return { things };
```

Comment: Indeed, it looks like the URL is generated from the name of that variaible and it is case sensitive... using `api/Things` would also work (though I'd expect this one is not recommended). Thank you.